# CSS Box Shadow Is using a shadow On Words When I don't want it to

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I am sort of new to coding but when adding a box-shadow to a navbar, it gives a shadow to the #href links as well. I do not want the words to have a shadow, just the bottom of the navbar.

```css
body {
      background-color: grey;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.4;
        color: var(--main-white);
    }
    
    #nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      z-index: 1;
      padding: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      color: #ffa2ae;
      box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #nav {
      background: #81f7ff;
    }
    
    *, *::before, *::after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
```

```html
<main> 
  <section id="nav" name="nav"> 
    <a href="#home" id="nav" name="home-nav">Home</a> 
    <a href="#purchase" id="nav" name="purchase-nav">Purchase</a> 
    <a href="#contact" id="nav" name="contact-nav">Contact</a> 
  </section>
</main>
```

[image: Here is what it looks like with the current CSS:]

Comment: Share your html code please.

Comment: ```<main>
    <section id="nav" name="nav">
      <a href="#home" id="nav" name="home-nav">Home</a>
      <a href="#purchase" id="nav" name="purchase-nav">Purchase</a>
      <a href="#contact" id="nav" name="contact-nav">Contact</a>
    </section>
  </nav>
</main>```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is, because your font/href is in the Navbar Tag if you look at your HTML file and so the Text gets the shadows from your navbar.
Try to add the href (or h1 , bzw whatever there is in your HTML file) in your css file and set the shatdows there to 0 or none.

Comment: I added my html code above can u please read that and maybe u could help me more? I tried changing the box-shadow to 0 on my <a> tag but it didnt work

Comment: I also tried adding this to my CSS:
```.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}```

It didn't work it just took the shadow away from everything.

Answer (score 0):

you first need to remove `id` from all `a` tag because `id` must be always unique and must be given for only one element. when you remove id from all `a` tag style won't be the same because of `nav` was styling `a` tag.

giving specific CSS for the specific tag solves your problem.

working demo:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}


body {
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: var(--main-white);
}
    
#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 35px;
  background: #81f7ff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#nav a{
    color: #ffa2ae;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="nav" name="nav">
    <a href="#home"  name="home-nav">Home</a>
    <a href="#purchase"  name="purchase-nav">Purchase</a>
    <a href="#contact"  name="contact-nav">Contact</a>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your anchor `ID` was the same to your parent ID which is `nav` so what you need to do is to remove it and this will fix your problem. Thanks

**CSS**

```
body {
      background-color: grey;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.4;
        color: var(--main-white);
    }

    #nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      background: #81f7ff;
    }

    #nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
         color: #ffa2ae;
    }


    *, *::before, *::after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
```

**HTML**

```
<main> 
  <section id="nav" name="nav"> 
    <a href="#home"  name="home-nav">Home</a> 
    <a href="#purchase"  name="purchase-nav">Purchase</a> 
    <a href="#contact"  name="contact-nav">Contact</a> 
  </section>
</main>
```